# Customizing path/to/plugin

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

According to the docs plugins and widgets are to be stored in /ckeditor_root/plugins/plugindir

As I plan to develop a widget for a content management system I would prefer to store the plugin in the assets of the cms.

Does ckeditor allow that by design?

Cheers,

Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable an extra plugin from a local folder, [`CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins-method-addExternal) must be called first so that CKEditor knew from where to load the plugin.

```
// Enable local "abbr" plugin from the "/myplugins/abbr/" folder.
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'abbr', '/myplugins/abbr/', 'plugin.js' );

// config.extraPlugins needs to be set, too.
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
   extraPlugins: 'abbr'
} );
```

The `CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal()` method accepts three parameters:

- The name of the plugin.
- The location of the plugin. Make sure that the path starts with a slash character ("/").
- The file name (usually "plugin.js").

Comment: Thank you so much, Anna. That is what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to help. If this solved your issue, can you mark the answer as accepted? This will help others who might seek a solution to the same problem in the future.

Comment: I assume it is the green tick on the left.